# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A0001' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting

When using this script:

```
DECLARE @FORDERBZV2     varchar(20)
DECLARE @FORDERBZV          varchar(20)

SELECT  @FORDERBZV      = (SELECT TOP 1 [FOR] FROM [Mil].[dbo].[FXO] where FOR like 'T0%' order by FOR desc)

--[FOR] is declared as varchar(20)  
SELECT  @FORDERBZV2 = right (@FORDERBZV, 19) + 1

--and after i run
insert into [Mil].[dbo].[FEO]
Values (@FORDERBZV2,....)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'T000005571' to data type int.

I don't understand why, because all fileds are declared as VARCHAR(20):

```
FOR from [Mil].[dbo].[FXO] = VARCHAR(20)
@FORDERBZV  =  VARCHAR(20)
@FORDERBZV  =  VARCHAR(20)
```

Also, the script will run correctly once, but when I try to run it a second time, I get the error.

Comment: How do you expect converting  "A0001" to integer? Is it supposed to be hexadecimal value you want to convert from?

Comment: The letter A is not a number.  Did I just say that?

Comment: Select @int = convert( int, substr(@var, 2,4) ) -> there is no (secure) way to know, what A converted to integer should be (the ASCII value? The Position in the Alphabet? shoe size of programmer?)

Comment: Why do you think it might be possible to convert 'A0001' to an integer?   Maybe there is another way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can use `TRY_CONVERT (int, @var)` instead. It will not raise an error and you are getting `NULL` values if the value is not an integer.

Comment: i am sorry have understand the Problem: at the first ttime The selects length = 20 but i have only see 10

Comment: example: 1 time = 'T000005571          '  after the script = 'T000005572' and the next time = error. when i fill all fith spaces afer number  = OK

Comment: "SELECT  @FORDERBZV2 = right (@FORDERBZV, 19) + 1"  Can't add the number 1 to a string.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem lies in this code line: `SELECT  @FORDERBZV2 = right (@FORDERBZV, 19) + 1`.
The reason you get the error is that your string is not actually 20 chars long, but it's shorter, so the `right` function simply returns the entire string.

I'm assuming you want to get the letter T following by zero-padded consecutive numbers, so you should probably do something like this:

```
DECLARE @FORDERBZV2     varchar(20)
DECLARE @FORDERBZV          varchar(20)

SELECT  @FORDERBZV      = (SELECT TOP 1 [FOR] 
                           FROM [Mil].[dbo].[FXO] 
                           WHERE [FOR] 
                           LIKE 'T0%' 
                           ORDER BY [FOR] DESC)

SELECT  @FORDERBZV2 = 'T' + RIGHT(
                            REPLICATE('0', LEN(@FORDERBZV)-1) + 
                            CAST (
                            CAST(RIGHT(@FORDERBZV, LEN(@FORDERBZV)-1) AS int) + 1 
                            AS varchar(20))
                            , LEN(@FORDERBZV)-1)

insert into [Mil].[dbo].[FEO]
Values (@FORDERBZV2,....)
```

[see fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/1725)